# Too Many Python Requests to Google Sheets Causing Error

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, slack, slack-api

I am currently creating a bot for my slack workspace that will record messages sent to a channel to a google sheet, as slack will delete messages after a few months and we want to keep track of messages from this channel in particular. Unfortunately, in testing, I've noticed that sending too many messages in this channel too quickly will cause errors.

Here is what my code looks like for reading/writing from/to the google sheet:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

path_to_credentials = ...

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(path_to_credentials, scopes=SCOPES)
spreadsheet_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
SPREADSHEET_ID = ...

def read_range(range):
    range_name = 'Sheet1!' + range
    spreadsheet_id = SPREADSHEET_ID
    result = spreadsheet_service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute()
    rows = result.get('values', [])
    return rows

def write_range(range, write_rows):
    spreadsheet_id = SPREADSHEET_ID
    range_name = 'Sheet1!' + range
    value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED'
    body = {
        'values': write_rows
    }
    result = spreadsheet_service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
        valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()
```

I get a few different errors when requests are sent too frequently. However, the stacktrace stays the same between errors. This is the stacktrace that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../srs/ApiMains/message_main.py", line 39, in message_main
    recordQuestionAndAnswerMessages(thread_ts=out_ts, name=name, message=text, ts=ts)
  File "../srs/ApiMains/message_main.py", line 131, in recordQuestionAndAnswerMessages
    write_range("A2:A2", [[next_col_num + 1]])
  File "../srs/util/sheets_util.py", line 32, in write_range
    result = spreadsheet_service.spreadsheets().values().update(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 844, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 183, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 164, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 197, in request
    response, content = self.http.request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1701, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1421, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1373, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1322, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
**ERROR MESSAGE HERE**
```

Here is a list of some of the different error messages I have received at the end of the stack trace:

- `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2607)`
- `OSError: [Errno 0] Error`
- `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2607)`

The WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER error is the one that occurs most frequently though. Does anyone know a bit more about what is happening and how I can fix it my issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer that worked ok for me. I used a queuing system. For each request, I create a uuid and write it to a text file. I then check whether or not the produced id is at the top of said text file. If it isn't, then delay for a few seconds and check again. If it is, do the request, and then afterward, remove the uuid from the queue. I do this in a text file so that all instances of the run will share this queue and be able to interact with it. It's a little janky, but it works! Here is what my solution looks like:

```
import uuid
import time as t

id = uuid.uuid4()
add_to_queue(id)
t.sleep(5)

file_to_open = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'util', 'google_sheet_queue.txt')
read_file = open(file_to_open, "r")
lines = read_file.readlines()
read_file.close()
while lines[0] != str(id) + "\n":
    t.sleep(3)
    read_file = open(file_to_open, "r")
    lines = read_file.readlines()
    read_file.close()

...

remove_from_queue(id)
return
```

This is what my adding and removing from the queue looks like:

```
def add_to_queue(id):
    file_to_open = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'google_sheet_queue.txt')
    with open(file_to_open, "a") as fp:
        fp.write(str(id) + "\n")

def remove_from_queue(id):
    file_to_open = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'google_sheet_queue.txt')
    with open(file_to_open, "r") as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()
    with open(file_to_open, "w") as write_file:
        for line in lines:
            if line != str(id) + "\n":
                write_file.write(line)
```